# hidden fields on subreport still visible in Word

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with some subreports. All hidden fields on the subreport are not hidden in the Word output, although they are not visible in the PDF output.
The content however is not visible.
The data I am showing is divided in 3 different tablixes, to achieve a 3 column table, where the data is filled first from left to right, then top to bottom.

Below the **Word** screenshot
[image]

and the **pdf** version

[image]

**Edit**: This does not only happen in this "multi tablix setup", but also in a subreport with a single tablix where some rows are hidden. Also here the row still shows, but the content is hidden (in Word) whereas the complete row should not be visible (which works fine in PDF)

I would like to have the Word output the same as the PDF output. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest, if possible, you redesign the report so you only use a single tablix. This article sounds like it might help...
https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12331/Simple-way-to-show-multi-column-data-in-SSRS-Horizontally-or-Vertically.html

Comment: @AlanSchofield I will certainly look into that article since it is a better way to create a multi column tablix. However, the problem does not occur only in this case, but also other subreports (see my edit)

Comment: Some things are only supported on certain renderers such as multi column format reports where you set the columns number in the report properties. Generally its better to not have the row come from the dataset if possible, rather than hiding them.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, sounds reasonable. Nevertheless, I also have subreports with a lot of rows where each row is set to hidden based on multiple conditions (aggregated results on a bigger sub-dataset). It would be quite cumbersome to convert all these conditions into a query. :-/
It is strange that this behaviour only appears on subreports; I have the same sort of hidden fields on the main report and those are working fine in Word. I was hoping there was some settging that has to be set on subreports to get this working...

Comment: Maybe filtering instead of hiding is an option?